# GCP: Restrict a firewall rule to a set of IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

I defined firewall rules to allow access from multiple source IPs. The source IPs are the same for each rule. I'd like to define those IPs at a single place and reuse it in each rule.

There is an option to filter the source to "sources tags", is it what I expect and where can I define theses "sources tags"?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the sources tags are only for internal traffic as indicated in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#sources_for_the_rule). So if you want to use source tags for traffic coming from external IPs, this would not be posible at the moment.

Nonetheless you could create a firewall rule allowing all the IPs you wanted and then apply it to instances with a specific [Network Tag](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags). This way you could have 1 rule and apply it to different VMs without need to modify the rule.